# Is there a way in Netbeans to count the number of project files?

Tags: file, netbeans, project

Pretty much as the question describes...

I am trying to get an idea as to what percentage of the total project files a sub-project modified.  I counted the files edited, but there are many, many files in the total project.

Is there a way to count all of the files included?

Answer (score 1):

[image]Easy way is open your Netbeans project folder, press ctrl+a and you can see the selected items information easily.

Comment: Yes, I can see whatever files I want, but I don't see a file count anywhere.  When I click on the "properties", I don't see any type of file count anywhere.  I also have multiple include paths, so viewing in the computer OS will take some time to gather the information together.  Can you tell me where I can see the selected item information?

Comment: @SableFoste In window it shows total files count and folders count, not aware about linux. But if it is not what you want than sorry.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I am using Windows, but I don't see what you are referring to anywhere.  I wonder if you have a plug-in installed that I do not?  In the lower right hand corner, I do see the file line number and character space.

Comment: @SableFoste If you will go to mydocuments NetBeans project folder, there if you select all the folders and do right click and see properties, in General Tab it will show total files and folders information. I just checked it showing all the info in general tabs. I wonder why is it not showing to you. I have added the image.

Comment: Thank you for adding the picture... I understand what you mean now.  Unfortunately, as I mentioned in my first comment, I have multiple include paths, plus I don't want to include all files (like images).  The native OS search feature is very manual.  What you have mentioned is the only way I know how, but I was hoping there was a shortcut somewhere.